# EXCEL: If function and refering to cell containing operator

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I don't know how to handle a cell which contain an operator and number.
Let's say I have 3 rows:

1. 2
2. 0,6
3. <0,1

In column B I have IF function which checks the number if it's greater or less than 1. How to handle the number with operator? Is there any other option than trimming one character before number? What if the operator will be "<=" in this case?

Comment: To remove the operator you could use the function `NUMBERVALUE(A1;",";"<")` That will remove the `<` operator only. You could use a formula like `=IF(NUMBERVALUE(A1;",";"<")=A1;A1>1;NUMBERVALUE(A1;",";"<")>=1)` to achieve what you want. Consider showing research effort on your next question posting what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If some cells have "<" and some don't then you can use `SUBSTITUTE` function to remove "<"

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1;"<";"")+0>1`

that will work even if there are no "<" symbols in A1

You can nest more SUBSTITUTE functions if you want to remove = or >, e.g.

`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1;"<";"");"=";"")+0>1`

or

`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1;"<";"");"=";"");">";"")+0>1`

I assumed that you use ; as argument separator in formula but that's region-specific, use comma instead of semi-colon if required

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula as follow :

=IF(MID(A3,2,3)>1,TRUE,FALSE)

I am assuming that **<0,1** is located in the A3 cell.

In **<0,1**  if you want to discard the "<" operator
try to use this function =MID(A3,2,3)
Check the [MID](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/mid-midb-functions-HP010342690.aspx) function syntax and example.